# Long running operation failed with status Failed

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-powershell

I've created an Azure Application Gateway (Azure RM) via Azure Powershell and it worked perfectly fine.Then I tried to create it using Azure SDK for Ruby (**Link to SDK**:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby) and received and Exception / Error that says "**Long running operation failed with status Failed**". When I looked at the Azure portal, Application Gateway was there with status Failed but there was no error in Audit logs.

I don't know why Azure is throwing exception. May be it's because Application Gateway creation is a long running operation.

Any idea how to cope with this problem and why I am receiving this error?